# Comparing AUC vs accuracy

Tags: roc, auc, accuracy

I understand this question has been asked many times however, i am unable to understand the answers well enough and apply to my situation.

I have attached 2 screenshots of my model. There are 5 class labels

Firstly this is a model with a lower accuracy but with a higher ROC area.

[image]

Then i have a model with a higher accuracy but a lower ROC area.

[image]

How do i decide which model is a better one if the cost for misclassification for all classes is the same

Comment: How can a model have multiple ROC Areas? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @calimo: I'd guess there are five classes & it's one of those extensions of ROC to the multinomial case. Perhaps aceminer can clarify.

Comment: @Calimo Yes there are 5 class labels